# Using a proprietary Dell keyboard key for something else

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, dell, alienware

I have a Dell G5 15 5500. It has "the G key" on it, which, in Windows, will tell Alienware Command Center to turn the fans to 100% and let the CPU turbo as high as possible. I was just wondering since Alienware Command Center doesn't exist on Ubuntu, is there a way to make that key do something else so it doesn't go completely unused?

Comment: command line execute `xev` and press that key. if you get a response: yes. if not: no

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes with a tool, `xev`, that provides information on keys you press and release. You will see information on "Keypress events" and "Keyrelease events" when you hit a key that is recognized and managed by the operating system.

If it is a key that directly talks to the hardware, you will see nothing while hitting it. Otherwise, you will be able to bind a command to it using Settings - Keyboard shortcuts in standard Ubuntu, or tools like `xbindkeys`.